# How to set -k , -v and --data-binary parameters within URLConnection

Tags: java, curl

I try to use the Nuance Dragon API for my Java Application.
Since I don't know anything about `cURL` I'm facing the problem to set the `-k , -v` and `--data-binary` parameters into the `URLConnection`-Object.

The cURL request:

```
curl "https://dictation.nuancemobility.net:443/NMDPAsrCmdServlet/dictation?appId=[INSERT YOUR APP ID]&appKey=[INSERT YOUR 128-BYTE STRING APP KEY]&id=C4461956B60B" 
-H "Content-Type: audio/x-wav;codec=pcm;bit=16;rate=8000" 
-H "Accept-Language: ENUS" 
-H "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" 
-H "Accept: application/xml" 
-H "Accept-Topic: Dictation" 
-k --data-binary @audio.wav  -v
```

My current code:

```
 URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
 connection.setDoOutput(true); 
 connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "ENUS");
 connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "audio/x-wav;codec=pcm;bit=16;rate=8000");
 connection.setRequestProperty("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");
 connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
 connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Topic", "Dictation");
```

Is there a simpler solution for this problem? Maybe a java-lib ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the [cURL man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) to see if you want to use any of those options. Especially `-v` would make no sense as a request property.

Comment: @SubOptimal thx for the info

Comment: Still cant get the solution. Could you please help me to  set the file to the URLConnection ?

Comment: You need to get an `InputStream` from the URLConnection and then write the file to it. An simple example can be found in the [Java networking tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html)